# Info on the site's graphical & ui design

Tags: discussion, user-interface

There is a lot of info out there about StackOverflow's internal architecture, its stack, server configuration, hardware, programming tools, IDE and what not, etc.

I am very curious about the UI & Graphic Design. Who designed it, how, what alternative designs where checked, etc. What other colors where checked, etc.

I mean the general site design and not the logo.

Answer (score 4):

[Podcast #16](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/podcast-16/) describes the early design of the site.  The initial layout and design was largely done by [Jeremy Kratz](http://www.jeremykratz.com/).  [This blog entry](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/stack-overflow-beta-design/) is a peek of the first "real" design.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the original "developer" version (May cause damage to kidneys and liver): http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-alpha.png